# Why does torch.gt function turn requires_grad into False?

Tags: python, pytorch

The `requires_grad` of tensor `b` and `c` are `True`. But the `requires_grad` of tensor `d` is `False`. I am curious why this change happens because all the `requires_grad` of inputs are True.

However, the `requires_grad` of tensor `e` is True. I can still do `backward()` on `e`. But is there an error in this way?

I am using Python3.7 and Pytorch1.1.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

net = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 3, padding=1)
a = torch.randn(1, 1, 10, 10)
b = net(a)
c = net(b)

d = torch.gt(b, c)

e = b - c
e[e > 0] = 1.0
e[e < 0] = 0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is because you cannot take a gradient of greater than operation. The return type is boolean:

```
>>> torch.gt(torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), torch.tensor([[1, 1], [4, 4]]))
tensor([[False, True], [False, False]])
```

Whereas minus or other arithmetic operation returns another numeral.